# How to have "/" forward slash in @RequestMapping?

Tags: spring-mvc, url-mapping

I have a requirement where the id I use in `@RequestMapping` accept a value of the format `1234567812345678` and `abcxyz/abcxy+z$` (basically a auto generated string with `/` forward slash in it).

I have tried a mapping of all the 3 below formats but nothing works:

`@RequestMapping(value="abc/action/{id: .+[//]*.*}.{format}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)`       -- Accepts nothing.

`@RequestMapping(value=" abc/action/{id:.+}.{format}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)`              -- Accepts everything except  `/`

`@RequestMapping(value=" abc/action/{id:.*}.{format}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)`               -- Accepts everything except  `/`

However, when I try the same regex in a normal java program, it works like a charm :

```
package miscellenousTest;
public class RegExTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 ="9876543298765432";
        String s2 =" abcxyz/abcxy+z$";
        System.out.println(s1.matches(".+[//]*.*"));
        System.out.println(s2.matches(".+[//]*.*"));
    }
}
```

I have gone through some of the previous posts but nothing gives me the exact solution I am looking for.

It will be great if someone can throw some pointers/solution at this one.

Comment: `/` isn't a backslash, it's a forward slash.

Comment: Or just slash.  But *most emphatically* ***not*** backslash.

Comment: You could write a filter to encode the oncoming request

Answer (score 1):

you should not use slashes when sending data in urls.  You will need to urlencode it before sending it.  It will then be decoded before being given back to you.

Sometimes I make web safe names when i come across this problem.  So for example i need to sometimes send ids like "12345/01".  When I send them over the web in urls, I say "12345_01", which we refer to as the web safe id.  we then convert it by replacing _ with / when we need the real id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lowe. However, this pattern of the encoding and decoding seems bit cumbersome and I cant always expect the client to call my webservice with an encoded url.

Could there be any other better way for this ? As mentioned in my post, I did try to play around with the regex to accept this pattern of data but that did not work.

Comment: if they wont call with an encoded url i suggest you work with web safe ids and real ids as 2 separate concepts.  whenever handing the id to the front end always give them the web safe one (no slashes), when working internally, use the real one.  However, i don't think its too much to ask the front end to encode values.  They have to do it for all get requests and its a simple method call.  Unfortunately, it's a bit like <, > in xml,  It needs encoding. Sometimes you just have to live and adjust to reserved characters when dealing with urls.